How can i allow players to add tiles on a tiled map (for my libGDX game project in JAVA)?
This is my first post on StackOverflow, lol, and I am making a tiled map game in JAVA using libGDX. i've already made the map using TiledMap software. Now i need to give players the ability to add buildings or objects (i'm assuming that allowing players to add object tiles is the only way to do that). I added some sprites as well, but i'm unsure about how to let players add tiles. I would appreciate if someone could explain the process and give an example code as well. ^-^
This is the GamePlay class that i have written so far...
public class GamePlay implements Screen {
private static final float ZOOM = 1f;

Viewport viewport;
TiledMap map;
OrthographicCamera camera;
TiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;

// Animated Tiles
AnimatedTiledMapTile animatedTile;

// People
SpriteBatch sb;
HashMap<String, Sprite> sprites;
TextureAtlas atlas;
TextureRegion textureRegion;

@Override
public void show() {

    // Screen width and height
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    // Camera settings
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(w, h, camera);
    camera.setToOrtho(false, w / ZOOM, h / ZOOM);
    camera.update();
    viewport.setScreenPosition(viewport.getScreenX(), viewport.getScreenY());

    // Map setting
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("map/Map1.tmx");
    mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

    // Sprite Batch creation
    sb = new SpriteBatch();

    // Sprite creation
    sprites = new HashMap<String, Sprite>(); // A hashmap for storing all my sprites with names.

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("atlas/Troops/Pawn_Purple.atlas");
    textureRegion = atlas.findRegion("Worker_Purple_Idle");
    sprites.put("Worker1", new Sprite(textureRegion));

    // Placing the sprite
    TiledMapTileLayer layer = ((TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(3));
    System.out.println(layer.getWidth() + " " + layer.getHeight());

    sprites.get("Worker1").setPosition(getCellWorldX(48), getCellWorldY(10));

    // Special keys
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputController() {
        public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
            if (keycode == Input.Keys.ESCAPE)
                ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.CONTROL_LEFT))
            camera.translate(-32, 0);
        camera.translate(-10, 0);
    }

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.CONTROL_LEFT))
            camera.translate(32, 0);
        camera.translate(10, 0);
    }

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)) {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.CONTROL_LEFT))
            camera.translate(0, -32);
        camera.translate(0, -10);
    }

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.CONTROL_LEFT))
            camera.translate(0, 32);
        camera.translate(0, 10);
    }

    // Map Rendering
    camera.update(); // Must update the camera view here or the map will not move,
    mapRenderer.setView(camera); // sets the updated view of the camera to be rendered
    mapRenderer.render(); // Renders the updated view.

    sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    // Sprite Rendering
    sb.begin();
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites.values()) {
        sprite.draw(sb);
    }

    // YET TO COMPLETE THIS ANIMATION
    int i = 0;
    sprites.get("Worker1").setRegion(atlas.findRegion("Worker_Purple_Idle", i));

    
    sb.end();

}
@Override
public void resize(int x, int y) {
    viewport.update(x,y, true);
    camera.update();

}
@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    map.dispose();
}

public float getCellWorldX(int x) {
    return x * 64;
}

public float getCellWorldY(int y) {
    return y * 64;
}

}

"Though i haven't really tried anything yet." Actually, you're precisely supposed to show what you have tried.
